# ImportError of standard Python modules with Jython (in JAR file)

Tags: java, jar, classpath, jython

I have implemented a Java application that includes Jython to run Python scripts. When I run that application from the IDE (Eclipse or IDEA), then all works fine, the Python scripts are processed correctly.

However, when I package everything into a JAR file (to be released), including the `jython.jar` file, then I get the following error as soon as the Java application tries to run the first Python script:

```
ImportError: No module named os
```

So it seems that the `Lib` folder with all the standard Python modules is not found. I checked the `jython.jar` file that is included in the Java application's JAR file, and it does include the `Lib` folder correctly. In fact, that is the same `jython.jar` file that is also used when I run the application from the IDE, where it works.

I know one can specify the `-Dpython.path` paramter, but I don't know what to set here. How can I refer to the the `Lib` folder which is within the `jython.jar` file which is within the main application's JAR file?

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same problem, here is my solution:
In your python script, add Lib path to sys path. Following is the code:

```
import sys
libPath="C:\\jython2.7b1\\Lib"
sys.path.append(libPath)
```

Comment: How does that help if the `Lib` folder is within the JAR file?